# Style manager configuration in openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am trying to the style from configuration and return My code is like this.

```
qt = {};
qt.gpn = qt.gpn || {};
qt.gpn.StyleManager = function(opts) {

    this.styleConfig = {
        Polygon: {
            layerStyle: function(feature, resolution)  {
                OpenLayer3 Style
            },
            legendText: [{
                strokeWidth: ,
                storkeColor: ,
                fillColor: ,
                displayText: 
            }, {
                strokeWidth: ,
                storkeColor: ,
                fillColor: ,
                displayText: 
            }]
        },
        Line: {
            layerStyle: function(feature, resolution)  {
                openLayer3 Style 
            },
            legendText: [{
                strokeWidth: ,
                storkeColor: ,
                fillColor: ,
                displayText: 
            }, {
                strokeWidth: ,
                storkeColor: ,
                fillColor: ,
                displayText: 
            }]
        }
    };

};

qt.gpn.StyleManager.prototype.getLayerStyle = function(layerId) {
    get it from config and return the style
};
```

I want to create a method to get the style from styleConfig for the given layer id and return style in javascript. Can someone help me

Comment: Try to start with [this example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/geojson.html).

Comment: Thanks but in my case I need define different colors for different polygons. in that example only one color for each feature is defined.

Comment: How about your data? Is a geojson file?

Comment: Take a look if it helps - http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/165021/50718